# how to write update procedure with scope identity

Tags: sql-server

My insert procedure is working fine the way i want. But update is not working with scope identity.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_unitCreation]
(
    @Unit_Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Unit_Abbreviation VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Unit_type VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Decimal_Places VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Description VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Super_Unit VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Per_Unit VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @unit_Id INT OUTPUT,
    @abc VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @abc = 'update' BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT @unit_Id AS SCOPE_IDENTITY

        UPDATE tbl_UnitCreation
        SET Unit_Name = @Unit_Name,
            Unit_Abbreviation = @Unit_Abbreviation,
            Unit_type = @Unit_type,
            Decimal_Places = @Decimal_Places,
            Description = @Description,
            Super_Unit = @Super_Unit,
            Per_Unit = @Per_Unit
        WHERE unit_Id = @unit_Id
    END

END

SELECT * FROM tbl_UnitCreation
```

Comment: `update is not working with scope identity` Are you getting an error?

Comment: Common scenario is to pass obtained after insert ID to all other SPs such as UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT. There are two options: 1) you control whole scenario and know exactly that update-SP comes right after insert-SP so you can (and actually must) pass new ID to update-SP 2) you don't control the scenario and cannot be sure that prior to update-SP call statement did insert row to the table you need, so you can't use ID obtained by SCOPE_IDENTITY() because you don't know which table this ID belongs to.

Comment: if you want to updated last inserted record then in that case use `IDENT_CURRENT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column. You are not inserting a row.

To update a row all you need is to pass a value to @unit_Id when executing [spr_unitCreation]. Also remove the line "SELECT @unit_Id AS SCOPE_IDENTITY" from your code.

Based on the comments, you need to find the correct id by searching on relevant details. So you can get the id like this:

```
SELECT @unit_Id = unit_Id
FROM tbl_UnitCreation
WHERE Unit_Name=@Unit_Name -- NB: Ensure this column contains your relevant details
```

Comment: ya thats the question. it should update automatically by id when we select relevent details. but with scope identity it is not taking unit_id=@unit_id

Comment: I've added to the answer. Which ever column(s) contain your relevant details should be in the where clause.

Comment: yes..but other columns are not always unique.i am using unit_id in my where clause because that is the only thing i have unique in my table

Comment: What did you mean earlier by "when we select relevant details"? How do you determine which row you want to update?

Comment: i want to update all columns in table except my unit_id which is primary key. how to do that with procedure

Answer (score 0):

Another commonly used option is to use the OUTPUT clause of the UPDATE statement, inserting all the updated/"inserted" primary keys and Unit_name into a tablevariable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017